# Pandas discard items in set using a different set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe; **parents** and **cte**. Both columns are made up of sets.  I want to use the **cte** column to discard overlapping items in the **parents** column. The dataframe is made up of over 6K rows.  Some of the **cte** rows have empty sets.

Below is a sample:

```
data = {'parents': [{'loan_agreement', 'select', 'opportunity', 'sales.dim_date', 'sales.flat_opportunity_detail', 'dets', 'dets2', 'channel_partner'}
,{'seed', 'dw_salesforce.sf_dw_partner_application'}], 
        'cte': [{'dets', 'dets2'}, {'seed'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I've used .discard(cte) previously but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
data = {'parents': [{'loan_agreement', 'select', 'opportunity', 'sales.dim_date', 'sales.flat_opportunity_detail', 'channel_partner'}
,{'dw_salesforce.sf_dw_partner_application'}], 
        'cte': [{'dets', 'dets2'}, {'seed'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

NOTE: dets, dets2 and seed have been removed from the corresponding **parents** cell.

Once the **cte** is compared to the **parents**, I don't need data from that row again. The next row will only compare data on that row and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop here.

A list comprehension will likely be the fastest:

```
df['parents'] = [P.difference(C) for P,C in zip(df['parents'], df['cte'])]
```

output:

```
                                             parents            cte
0  {channel_partner, select, opportunity, loan_ag...  {dets, dets2}
1          {dw_salesforce.sf_dw_partner_application}         {seed}
```